# Remove punctuation (comma) after volume number in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Using this code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 
% Unix options
\isopage
\usepackage{etex,setspace,excludeonly,ifthen,etoolbox,logreq,makeidx,cals,graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-classic,firstinits,uniquename=init,natbib=true,backend=biber,indexing=true,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibcheck{Thinking}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{journaltitle}{Thinking}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{noThinking}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{journaltitle}{Thinking}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}

\addbibresource{thesis.bib} 

% Style alterations: parentheses around place: publisher and colon between vol
% and no
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{% ADDED
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
%      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
 {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
  }\nopunct% ADDED
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
%  \setunit*{\addcolon}% ADDED
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography[category=cited,check=noThinking,prenote={JoPE},title={Bibliography excluding articles in \emph{Thinking: The Journal of Philosophy for Children}}]

\end{document}
```

and this bibliography entry in thesis.bib

```
@article{Allhoff2005,
author = {Allhoff, Fritz},
file = {:Users/study\_mini/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Allhoff - 2005 - A Defense of Torture Separation of Cases, Ticking Time-bombs, and Moral Justification.pdf:pdf},
journal = {International Journal of Applied Philosophy},
keywords = {ch5},
mendeley-tags = {ch5},
number = {2},
pages = {243--264},
title = {{A Defense of Torture: Separation of Cases, Ticking Time-bombs, and Moral Justification}},
volume = {19},
year = {2005}
}
@inbook{1Almond2010,
    year={2010},
    Crossref = {9BaileyHandbook2010},
    booktitle={The Sage Handbook of Philosophy of Education},
    title={The Value of Knowledge},
    author={Brenda Almond},
    chapter={20},
    pages={297--306}
```

I get in my bibliography:

> volume.number, pp. ...

I wish to remove the comma after number but deleting `\addcomma` does not make any difference to the final output. Do I need a `\renewcommand` instead or a tweak to my existing code?

Comment: Hi! Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think I've done this now.

Comment: @DGarside Add the following to you preamble if you want to replace the punctuation in front of the page numbers by a space: `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}` Naturally you can also remove the space or use a different separator. Note that your example is not exactly minimal, and it also does not compile in the present form. Among other things, the `prenote={JoPE}` does not compile, you don't cite any of the references and `Crossref = {9BaileyHandbook2010}` is not provided.

Answer (score 8):

You only need one line

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}
```

This tells `biblatex` to only put a space right before the pages, no other punctuation.

You can force this for `@article`s only by using

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-classic,firstinits,uniquename=init,natbib=true,backend=biber,indexing=true,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Allhoff2005,
author = {Allhoff, Fritz},
journal = {International Journal of Applied Philosophy},
keywords = {ch5},
mendeley-tags = {ch5},
number = {2},
pages = {243--264},
title = {{A Defense of Torture: Separation of Cases, Ticking Time-bombs, and Moral Justification}},
volume = {19},
year = {2005}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
%  \setunit*{\addcolon}% ADDED
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]